# Not able to create a variable named `name` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript in browser's console and defining a variable as :

```
const name = {firstName: 'hello', lastName: 'world'};
```

Whenever I'm trying to log name, it gives me `[object Object]`, instead of giving me `Object: {firstName: "hello", lastName: "world", __proto__: Object}`

However when I'm creating a constant of other *variable name*, it is working fine

[**Edit**]: Snippet of code :

[image]

Comment: Works just fine in the Javascript console in Firefox. Please show a larger code snippet.

Comment: Please provide information on what browser and version you're using.

Comment: @MeterLongCat I'm using `Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)`

Comment: Thanks Barmer for marking it duplicate :)